# Does instability make an otherwise LTI system nonlinear (or time-variant)?

Tags: linear-systems, transfer-function

I am spinning this question off from the [question from johnny](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18431/is-this-system-linear).  Matt L. and I have had directly opposite conclusions to johnny's question.

I want to decouple the question from issues of causality and other goofy stuff.

So we have a simple first-order recursive system described with time-domain I/O equation:

$$ y[n] = p \cdot y[n-1] \ + \ x[n] \quad \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$

Of course, the Z-transform of this is

$$ Y(z) = p \cdot z^{-1} Y(z) \ + \ X(z) $$

and transfer function

$$ H(z) \triangleq \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{z}{z-p} $$

We would normally identify this as a simple and realizable LTI system with a zero at $0$ and a pole at $p$.  But in the other question, there is an issue regarding linearity and time-invariance for the case when $p=-1 \ $.

For what values $p$ is this system linear?  For what values $p$ is this system time-invariant?

This is, I believe, the kernel of the disagreement I have with Dr. Matt L.

Comment: If we expand it to its fir form. Theoretically the system is always linear.

Comment: okay @learner , so if $p=-1$, then MattL suggests you can have for input $x[n]=0 \ \forall n$ the output $$ y[n] = A (-1)^n \quad \forall A \in \mathbb{R} $$ including non-zero $A$.  input is identically zero, output is non-zero.  can that system be linear?

Comment: Please clarify: for _what_ integers $n$ does the relationship $$y[n] = p \cdot y[n-1] \ + \ x[n]$$ hold? For _all_ integers $n$? For $n \geq 0$? For $n > 0$?  And in the latter two cases, please specify what is the value of $y[-1]$ (respectively $y[0]$) since we are agreed that $y[0]=-py[-1]+x[0]$ or $y[1]=-py[0]+x[1]$.

Comment: i had never placed a restriction on it.  in the other question, i was explicit that $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  i should have said so here, but i neglected to.  so i will modify the question.  in my opinion, if not specified, the assumption is that there is no restriction.

Comment: and since $$ y[n] = \sum\limits_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty} h[i] x[n-i] $$ you can derive $y[0]$ or any other specific $y[n]$ from that.  if you assume causality, you get a right-sided $h[n]$.  if you assume anti-causality (which is not the way i stated the difference equation), you get a left-sided $h[n]$.  in either case that affects one limit or the other for the convolution summation.

Comment: Your question has no answer in that a system that is _not_ BIBO-stable cannot be said to be _linear_ at all. Remember that the _definition_ of linearity says that for _any_ (bounded) input sequences $x_1[\cdot]$ and $x_2[\cdot]$ that produce outputs $y_1[\cdot]$ and $y_2[\cdot]$ respectively, the system must produce output $a\cdot y_1[\cdot]+b\cdot y_2[\cdot]$ when the input is $a\cdot x_1[\cdot]+b\cdot x_2[\cdot]$. But when $x_1[\cdot]$ is one of those bounded sequences that produce unbounded outputs, then the assertion that the output equals $a\cdot y_1[\cdot]+b\cdot y_2[\cdot]$ is not valid

Comment: (continued) at all: we cannot assert that $\infty = \infty$ and so the output is indeed the linear combination of the component outputs.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, if $p=1$ or $p=0$ or $p=-1$, isn't that BIBO stable?  seems to me it would be.

Comment: The system of course is linear. Linearity do *not* mean Affinity (y=0 when x=0). Linearity do *not* imply Stability. Linearity do *not* imply time-variability. If p=p(t), system is time-varying.

Comment: only if p equals 0, @hypfco.  otherwise it doesn't satisfy *"additivity"* or *"super-position"*.  for operator $\mathscr{T}\{\cdot\}$ to be linear, we need $$ \mathscr{T}\{x_1(t) + x_2(t)\} = \mathscr{T}\{x_1(t)\} + \mathscr{T}\{x_2(t)\}$$

Comment: Sorry, i missed a term. Keeping the same question, $y[n]=py[n-1]+x[n]$: is linear for every $a_1$,$a_2$,$x_1$,$x_2$: $a_1y_1[n]+a_2y_2[n]=p(a_1y_1[n-1]+a_2y_2[n-1])+a_1x_1[n]+a_2x_2[n]$; is time invariant if $p(t)=p$ constant for every $n_0$: $y[n_0]=py[n_0-1]+x[n_0]$.

Comment: For this we need $y[0]=0$, the initial condition (which leads to a zero homogeneous solution of the DE). Under that, $x[n]=0$ implies $y[n]=0$ for every $p$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how the discussion arrived to this point but it is pretty convoluted to follow after this much of time. It is an ordinary difference equation with constant coefficients thus defines a linear, time invariant system. There is no need to pursue further from that **if a unique solution exists**. Here we have a problem with the emphasized part.

Let's first write the descriptor state space equations: the system is described by

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}s_1[k+1]\\s_2[k+1]\end{bmatrix} &=
\begin{bmatrix}p&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}s_1[k]\\s_2[k]\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}x[k]\\
y[k] &= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}s_1[k]\\s_2[k]\end{bmatrix}
+[1]x[k]
\end{align}
$$

Now this is where I think the problematic part is. This system, though being LTI, is not regular (relevant buzz words are *regular*, *impulse-free*, index-1 descriptor systems). In other words, there exists no $\lambda$ for which the expression $\det(\lambda E-A)$ is nonzero and hence one of the modes is $\frac{\bullet}{0}$ and in fact this is $\frac{0}{0}$ for this example. This means that our system has solution uniqueness issues, unlike the causal LTI system, there is no guarantee on the existence of a unique solution. There is no guarantee of an admissible solution for that matter(buzzword impulsive systems). Hence the LTI reasoning of the other answers won't cut it.

And this what causes the trouble as far as I can tell from Matt L's argument is that he found two nontrivially distinct solutions for the same system and concluded that this cannot be a linear system. But this also assumes the uniqueness and existence of a solution and initial conditions.

It only differs from the *regular* systems in the way that the uniqueness and existence guarantees of the standard LTI systems cannot be assumed. The models no longer can be assumed to have admissible trajectories for all possible signals.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. In order to label a discrete-time system as LTI, we only look for its linearity and time invariance properties and don't need to care whether it is stable or not. That is another independent property of a system that can mutually co-exist with other properties. And indeed many LTI systems are unstable and they are still LTI systems. For abundance of examples please refer to Alan Oppenheim's book: Signals & Systems, 2ed, chapter 2. (or any other college text book on signals & and systems, or digital signal processing)
Consider for example non stable IIR filters which are still linear and time invariant. (indeed your example is one such)

Coming to your LCDDE that is supposed define a recursive discrete time system, as you may know, the LCDDE itself is not enough to uniquely specify a solution, as you also need a set of auxiliary conditions (initial conditions). Without those initial conditions explicitly set, you can neither solve the equation, nor determine whether the system it represents will be LTI or causal. Because for some initial conditions, it may be non causal, non linear and time varying, while for some other set (namely the initial rest conditions) it will be linear, time invariant and causal. Therefore in order for a single LCCDE to uniquely represent a LTI system its initial conditions must be properly set to initial rest and not arbitrarily...

Answer (score 0):

Linearity and time-invariance do not depend on the value of $p$. The two possible linear and time-invariant (LTI) systems described by the difference equation

$$y[n]=p\cdot y[n-1]+x[n]\tag{1},\quad p\neq 0$$

are given by the inverse $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of the transfer function as formulated in the question:

$$H(z)=\frac{z}{z-p}\tag{2}$$

Note that (2) does not uniquely define an impulse response unless the region of convergence (ROC) of $H(z)$ is given. For the transfer function (2), there are two possible ROCs: $|z|>|p|$ and $|z|<|p|$. In the first case, the corresponding impulse response is right-sided and corresponds to a causal LTI system:

$$h_1[n]=p^nu[n]\tag{3}$$

where $u[n]$ is the unit step function. If we choose $|z|<|p|$ as the ROC, we get a left-sided impulse response corresponding to an anti-causal system:

$$h_2[n]=-p^nu[-n-1]\tag{4}$$

If $|p|<1$ then the causal LTI system characterized by $h_1[n]$ is stable, and the anti-causal LTI system characterized by $h_2[n]$ is unstable, and if $|p|\ge 1$ the opposite holds.

So far we have seen that the difference equation (1) defines two LTI systems, one causal and the other one anti-causal. The two corresponding impulse responses $h_1[n]$ and $h_2[n]$ are solutions of the difference equation (1) for $x[n]=\delta[n]$. However, these are not the only solutions of (1). It is well-known from the theory of linear difference equations that the general solution is given by a particular solution for some given $x[n]$, and by a solution to the homogeneous equation defined by $x[n]=0$. For the given difference equation, the corresponding homogeneous equation is

$$y[n]=p\cdot y[n-1]\tag{5}$$

The solution of (5) is

$$y_h[n]=c\cdot p^n,\quad c\in \mathbf{R}\tag{6}$$

Now we can express the general solution of (1) (with $x[n]=\delta[n]$) by combining a particular solution (either $h_1[n]$ or $h_2[n]$) with $y_h[n]$:

$$y[n]=h_1[n]+y_h[n]=h_1[n]+c\cdot p^n\tag{7}$$

Note that the solution $h_2[n]$ can be obtained from (7) by choosing $c=-1$. Also note that (7) is valid for all $n\in\mathbf{Z}$.

If we were to scale the input signal and use $x_1[n]=a\delta[n]$ with some $a\in\mathbf{R}$, the resulting output would be

$$y_1[n]=a\cdot h_1[n]+c\cdot p^n\tag{8}$$

This output signal is generally not equal to $a\cdot y[n]$ (with $y[n]$ given by (7)), unless $c=0$ or $c=-1$. Consequently, the corresponding system is not linear. For the input signal $x_2=\delta[n-n_0]$ the output is

$$y_2[n]=h_1[n-n_0]+c\cdot p^n\tag{9}$$

which is generally not equal to $y[n-n_0]$ (again, unless $c=0$ or $c=-1$). So the corresponding system is also not time-invariant.

In sum, the difference equation (1) describes infinitely many systems with responses to the input signal $x[n]=\delta[n]$ given by (7). Only two of these systems are LTI, the others are not. The two LTI systems are described by the impulse responses $h_1[n]$ and $h_2[n]$ given by (3) and (4), respectively.

Comment: so, bottom line, the system described by this equation $$ y[n] = p \cdot y[n-1] \ + \ x[n] \quad \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$ is not LTI.  or not necessarily LTI.  right? $$ \ $$  now, to simplify the discussion, can you agree that the reason you assert that it is not LTI is because with an input that is identically zero $$x[n]=0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$, that the output can be non-zero $$ y[n] = c \cdot p^n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$ and $c \ne 0 \ $?

Comment: also, if $p=0$, might that be an exception to your initial assertion that *"Linearity and time-invariance do not depend on the value of $p$"*?

Comment: and lastly, are you are apparently denying that, even for a properly chosen $h[n]$, that $$ y[n] = \sum\limits_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty} h[i] x[n-i] $$ cannot be a general solution to $$ y[n] = p \cdot y[n-1] \ + \ x[n] \quad \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$ or systems described similarly?

Comment: MattL, are you interested in addressing **any** of these questions?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Yes, but you seem to ask many questions at the same time, and I feel that most of them have already been answered explicitly by my answer to your original question. But I'll give it a go ...

Comment: Yes, as I've tried to make clear in my answer, the LDE describes LTI systems as well as other systems (that are not LTI). And yes, the fact that the output is non-zero with zero input is one reason why the respective systems can't be LTI.

Comment: The case $p=0$ is a trivial and uninteresting case, and for this reason I did not address it in my answer. What's the point?

Comment: As I've already shown, the solution(s) formulated by a convolution sum cannot describe *all* possible solutions of the LDE. They are *particular* solutions, not a general solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if you agree but our discussion seems to have arrived at a dead end. I feel I've said everything I have to say, and if you choose to have a different opinion I will have to live with it. I'm not on a mission to change your mind. I'm pretty happy with my answer and I haven't yet found a reason to change it.

Comment: *"The case $p=0$ is a trivial and uninteresting case, and for this reason I did not address it in my answer. What's the point?"*  $$  $$ the point is about crossing our i's and dotting our t's. and about being consistent about it.

Comment: *"...the fact that the output is non-zero with zero input is one reason why the respective systems can't be LTI."* well, the bottom line is that is the **sole** causal reason. it is only with this postulation that you can create your counter-examples $y_1[n]$ and $y_2[n]$. and we can part ways with our answers, but i can guarantee you that your answer would be marked incorrect in a typical EE class, whether it's an $H(s)$ or an $H(z)$, as long as all time $t$ or $n$ is considered. it's because not all *possible* solutions are solutions and, in your case, there is nothing to make $y[0] \ne 0$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I agree that the discussion is quite theoretical, but I hope that there has never been any doubt about that. The practical importance of it becomes apparent when you actually implement such a (causal) difference equation, in which case you have to choose an initial condition, and if - often by mistake - you don't initialize your memory with zeros, you get a system which is neither linear nor time-invariant, and most people don't know or at least don't realize it. Anyway, I think we can close the case now as we seem to have reached some kind of agreement.

Comment: *"The practical importance of it becomes apparent when you actually implement such a (causal) difference equation, in which case you have to choose an initial condition,"* no, you don't.  there is no choice. *"and if - often by mistake - you don't initialize your memory with zeros, you get a system which is neither linear nor time-invariant, and most people don't know or at least don't realize it."*  you get a click or a "pop".  an identical click or pop as you would get with the equivalent $x[n]$ for $n<0$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Of course you have a choice and you must choose. How do YOU implement $y[n]=py[n-1]+x[n]$? If you start your recursion at a certain finite time, say $n_0$, i.e. you consider input and output from that time on (and what else could you do if you forgot to switch on your system at $n=-\infty$?), you have to choose a value for $y[n_0-1]$. If you don't, then you implicitly choose it as $y[n_0-1]=0$ anyway, so you always choose. But you're right, it's no big deal as long as the system is stable.

Comment: sure, i s'pose you can choose to implement a system that you're not modeling.  i know about initial conditions.  in audio, we discuss the four essential processes of a real-time audio DSP process.  there is (1) the sample-processing in which the difference equation is executed.  there is (2) coefficient cooking and (3) metering.  and there is (4) initialization.  if you don't initialize the states to zero, you're not implementing the model.  if you **multiply** two samples together (instead of adding), you're not implementing the model.  my point is...

Comment: ... if you're implementing the model, then any of the states at $n=0$ are a linear combination of $x[n]$ for $n=0$ (at least if the system is "controllable").  in particular $$ y[n] = \sum\limits_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty} h[i] x[n-i] $$ so the initial condition **is** a linear combination of the $x[n]$ preceding it.  namely $$ y[0] = \sum\limits_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty} h[i] x[-i] $$ and, if it's causal, then $$ y[0] = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{+\infty} h[i] x[-i] $$.  that satisfies the LTI criteria.

Comment: you have no more choice is mis-setting the states in the model than you do in mis-calculating coefficients or simply implementing the difference equations incorrectly.  and you don't have a choice in setting states at $n=-\infty$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Again, if you start at $n=n_0$ then you don't see any $x[n]$ for $n<n_0$, because your system doesn't process it (i.e. it's not in its memory). So, the first sample you need to compute is $y[n_0]=py[n_0-1]+x[n_0]$. No way to compute it unless you *choose* $y[n_0-1]$. And this is always the case when you actually implement a recursive system. You can start your recursion whenever you like, but it's going to be a finite value $n_0$. Before that, everything is unknown to the system.

Comment: too late to edit a mistake: meant to say *"if you're implementing the model, then any of the states at $n=0$ are a linear combination of $x[n]$ for $n\le0$ (at least if the system is "controllable")."*

Answer (score 0):

I find this discussion intriguing and I wanted to add another viewpoint to the mix:

The system under consideration ( $y[n]=p⋅y[n−1] + x[n]$ ) can be thought of as a mapping from one (infinite dimensional) vector space to another. Let's call this this mapping $M$, and we can (initially) define it as:

$$ M : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z} $$

This terminology says that $M$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ (the space of all real-valued functions of an integer variable) to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$.

If system has any zeros (and the system under consideration here has a zero at $z=1$), this means that our mapping $M$ is not one-to-one, because two different input signals will lead to the same output signal. For example, for any input signal, $x[n]$, we can say that $M(x)=M(x+\lambda)$ for any real $\lambda$.

The set of functions that are "zeros" of our system can be defined as:

$$K_{zeros}=\{f[n]=\lambda:\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Likewise, we note that if our system has any poles (and the system under consideration here has a zero at $z=-1$), then this means that the inverse mapping, $M^{-1}$ is not one-to-one. Specifically, $M^{-1}(x)=M^{-1}(x+\lambda(-1)^n)$ for any real $\lambda$.

The set of functions that are "poles" of our system can be defined as:

$$K_{poles}=\{f[n]=\lambda(-1)^n:\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Now, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ is a vector space, $K_{zeros}$ is a vector space, and $K_{poles}$ is a vector space.

We can now define two *quotient spaces* (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Subspaces_and_quotient_spaces) for more information about quotient spaces):

$$ Q_{input} = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z} / K_{zeros} $$

$$ Q_{output} = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z} / K_{poles} $$

You can think of $Q_{output}$ as being the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ that does not contain any signal components of the form $\lambda(-1)^n$, or alternatively, you can think of $Q_{output}$ as being identical to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ with *equivalence classes* that tell us "for our current application, we will consider any function $y[n]$ to be *eqivalent* to $y[n]+\lambda(-1)^n$ for any real $\lambda$"

By doing this, we can now redefine a new mapping $M'$ as a mapping from $Q_{input}$ to $Q_{output}$. This new mapping is really just the same as our old mapping, $M$, except we've reduced the vector-spaces on which it operates. Furthermore, this new mapping is now a bijection (it's "one-to-one" and "onto"), so it is guaranteed to also be invertible.

Finally, this mapping, $M'$ is **linear**.

So, the point of this whole rambling explanation is that, by defining the appropriate equivalence classes (or alternatively, by restricting our space of allowable functions to a sub-space of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$), we can maintain the property that our mapping should be linear (and time-invariant).

For example, the rules of **linearity** tell us that, if $x[n]$ is an input signal and $\alpha$ is any real scalar, then $M(\alpha x) = \alpha M(x)$. Hence, this implies that, by setting $\alpha=0$, we should therefore expect that $M(0\times x)=y[n]=0$ (i.e. if we input the zero-signal to our filter, the output should be $y[n]=0$).

However, we know that it's possible for have a situation where the input to the filter is zero, but the output is of the form $y'[n]=(-1)^n$, so we might be tempted to say "that proves our system is not linear, because $y'[n]$ is not zero". However, you will recall that the *equivalence class* we have enforced on the output vector space says that "for our current application, we will consider any function $y[n]$ to be *eqivalent* to $y[n]+\lambda(-1)^n$ for any real $\lambda$", which means that $y'[n]=(-1)^n$ is *equivalent* to zero!