# Linearity of the given system

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems

I am given the following system and I am checking the additive property:

$$y(t)=x(e^t)$$

where $y(t)$ is the output and $x(t)$ is the input given to the system.

Now this is what I did so far:

\begin{align}
x_1(t)&\rightarrow \text{system} \rightarrow& y_1(t)=&x_1(e^t)\\
x_2(t)&\rightarrow \text{system} \rightarrow& y_2(t)=&x_2(e^t)\\
\end{align}

$$y_1(t) + y_2(t) = x_1(e^t) + x_2(e^t)$$
How will system respond to this input?

$$x_1(t) + x_2(t)\rightarrow system \rightarrow = $$

What I think is that this is what will happen:

$$x_1(t) + x_2(t)\rightarrow system \rightarrow = x_1(e^t)+x_2(e^t)$$

Am I right?

Comment: What do $y$ and $x$ represent in the first equation you wrote ($y(t)=x(e^t)$)?

Comment: I think you are right. A system is additive if $S\{ x_1(t) + x_2(t) \} = S\{ x_1(t) \} + S\{ x_2(t) \}$, where $S\{ \cdot \}$ is the system.

Comment: $y(t)=x(t)$ describes a perfect system where signals enter and leave undistorted. Do you think you could clarify the question a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additivity requires a little more than a direct addition of some $x_1$ to some $x_2$. It should involve **any linear combination** of  $x_1$ and $x_2$, $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2$ where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are "kind of scalars" (this could make us dive into complicated stuff, like in  [Does scaling property imply superposition?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24999/15892))

In your case, however, linearity works, because you are touching the "time base" ($t$ vs. $e^t$) without touching the amplitudes. Your operation is a sort of time warping.

Accordingly:

$$\mathcal{S}(a_1 x_1(t) + a_2 x_2(t)) = a_1 x_1(e^t) + a_2 x_2(e^t) = \mathcal{S}(a_1 x_1(t)) + \mathcal{S}(a_2 x_2(t))  $$

Comment: Afaik it sufficies for $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be complex? What other complications did you imply? (or did you?) I read from the other link that you mention about irrational and rational number fields...

Comment: If, if inputs ans outputs are real or complex. In some rare cases, they belong to another structure (like values in a finite field)